# Filter queryset by checking element entrance in array in django

Tags: python, django, database

I have a movie model and it has genres array, which contains ids of Genre model. How can i filter movies by checking some one genre id entry in arrays of Film model?

Just like

```
Film.objects.filter(genres__in=[1, 4, 7])
```

but vice versa.

```
Film.objects.filter(genres__has=genre_id)
```

Comment: `Film.objects.filter(genres__id__in=genres_array)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `genres` is a [**`ManyToManyField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) relation, you can just **filter on the field**:

```
Film.objects.filter(genres=genre_id)  # movies with at least genre_id
```

In that case, Django will perform a `JOIN` on the many-to-many relation table, and filter that table on the `genre_id`, hence we obtain the movies where the collection of genres contains at least the `genre_id` we filter with.